# Design questions for using RavenDB for reporting

Tags: reporting, ravendb

I'm working on a project where I am collecting data from different sources, and afterwards I need to do some reporting on that data. All the reports are predefined.

I'm thinking of using RavenDB for this, as I think the indexes and map/reduce part could be a good fit for this, so that I create an index for each report.

Is the one-index-per-report the way to go, or does that come with any pitfalls? And how about index starvation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One-index-per-report will lead to lots of extra indexes.  Think instead of "one-index-per-dataset".  Then build multiple reports around each dataset.

There might be more than one dataset per collection if you are doing map/reduce.  For example, you might have the following indexes:

- OrderDetailsIndex
- OrderTotalsByCustomer
- OrderTotalsByMonth
- OrderTotalsByDay
- OrderTotalsByProduct

You could build many reports from these indexes.

What you *don't* want to do is to have multiple indexes like:

- OrdersByCustomer
- OrdersByDate
- OrdersByZipCode

Those are just multiple maps that can be condensed into the same index, so it would be redundant to split them apart.

If you had one index per report, it would get out of control quickly:

- OrderDetailsIndex_ForReportA
- OrderDetailsIndex_ForReportB

The only difference between A and B might be the layout of the fields.

And finally, you might want to consider upgrading to RavenDB 2.5.  There is a new feature called "Streaming Unbounded Results", that you can read about [in Ayende's blog](http://ayende.com/blog/161249/ravendbs-querying-streaming-unbounded-results).  This is probably the best way to feed data from an index into a report.  If your reporting engine requires an `IEnumerable` data source (most do), then you might want to use [this handy extension method I wrote](https://gist.github.com/mj1856/5834645).